# Extracting Google Earth elevation data to Excel?

Tags: google-earth, elevation, excel

I have a polyline in Google Earth.

I am able to see the elevation profile in Google Earth when I move along the polyline but is there a way to extract the lat,long and elevation data out to Excel?

Comment: My first thought is that depending on your intended use, this may violate the [Google Terms of Service](http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html), as a derivative work.  My second thought would be that it would be simpler to bring your polyline into ArcGIS, load in a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from USGS, at [The National Map](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/) and extract your elevations directly than doing a multi-step process out of GE.

Answer (score 10):

The [GEOCONTEXT-PROFILER](http://www.geocontext.org/publ/2010/04/profiler/en/) will create an elevation profile just like Google Earth and you can import a KML and export a CSV.  It should give you the same results as Google Earth.

[This is](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en#section_10_12) the license restriction page that the tool links to.

Answer (score 5):

The [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) can give you the elevation at any point on earth, so you can iterate across your polyline and get the elevation of each point:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034|36.455556,-116.866667 :

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.7391536,
            "lng" : -104.9847034
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      },
      {
         "elevation" : -50.78903579711914,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 36.455556,
            "lng" : -116.866667
         },
         "resolution" : 19.08790397644043
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Up to 2,500 requests per day are available for free.  Note that the terms of service require you to display any obtained results on a Google map, and calling the API from Excel or ArcGIS is likely to be a little complicated.